# How to make c programe as daemon in ubuntu?

Tags: c, ubuntu, daemon

Hi I am new to the linux environment. I am trying to create daemon process.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int  main()
{
int a=10,b=10,c;
c=sum(a,b);
printf("%d",c);
return (0);
}
int sum(int a,int b)
{
return a+b;
}
```

I want to create daemon process of it. May i know how can do this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I believe you don't exactly understand what is job control, what is a daemon process.

Answer (score 3):

A daemon generally doesn't use its standard input and output streams, so it is unclear how your program could be run as a daemon. And a daemon program usually don't have any terminal, so it cannot use `clrscr`. Read also the [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) page, and also [daemon(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/daemon.7.html).

I recommend reading some good introduction to Linux programming, like the old freely downloadable [ALP](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf) (or something newer). We can't explain all of it here, and you need to read an entire book. See also [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html) and [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html).

I also recommend reading more about OSes, e.g. the freely available [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) textbook.

You could use the [daemon(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html) function in your C program to run it as a daemon (but then, you are likely to not have any input and output). You may want to log messages using [syslog(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html).

You might consider [job control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_(Unix)) facilities of your shell. You could run your program in the background (e.g. type  `myprog myarg &` in your interactive shell). You could use the `batch` command. However neither background processes nor batch jobs are technically daemons.

Perhaps you want to code some [ONC-RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Network_Computing_Remote_Procedure_Call) or [JSONRPC](http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification) or [Web API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_API) server and client. You'll find libraries for that. See also [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html), [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html)

<sup>(take several days or several weeks to read much more)</sup>

Comment: Ok sorry let's say if I have hard coded values rather thank taking from keyboard. In such cases how can I make this as daemon

Comment: AS I wrote, you could use the `daemon` function

Answer (score 2):

First find what are the properties of `daemon process`, as of my knowledge a daemon process have these properties:

- Should `not` have `any parent` (it itself should be parent)
  Process itself is a `session leader`.
- Environment change to `root`.
- File mode creating `mask` should be `zero`.
- No controlling terminal.
- All terminal should be `removed`
- Should not be `un-mounted` .

Implement the code by considering above properties which is

```
int i=0;
int main()
{
        int pid;
        pid=fork();
        if(pid!=0) {
         /** you can add your task here , whatever you want to run in background **/
                exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
                setsid();//setting sessions
                chdir("/");//root.. should'nt beunmounted
                umask(0);
                close(0);//all terminal are removed
                close(1);
                close(2);
                while(1)
                {
                        printf("i = %d \n",i);
                        i++;
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

or you can go through man page of `daemon()`

```
 int daemon(int nochdir, int noclose);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. In the above c program no need to add header file?

Comment: RTFM: The [daemon(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html) and [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) `man` pages are detailing the required headers.

Comment: yes of course you need to add header file. open man page of each  system call, you will get headers.

Comment: Also after making above programe as daemon can i use this daemon in c# program?

Comment: C and C# are completely different programming languages (and likewise C++ is different from C). Please choose which programming language you want to code it.

Comment: Actually what i am trying is lets say i have one c programe with function sum,subtract etc. I want to access this functions from my c# code. someone told me to use daemon. May i know daemon is the right way to do this?

Comment: Your question becomes too broad. You seems very confused. You need to read *several* books before coding and spend more than a week in reading and learning.

Comment: I am .net developer and this is task assigned to me by my superior. May i know which is the correct way to do this? accordingly i will learn.

Comment: I don't understand what you want, and you don't seem to understand it neither. Maybe you need to speak with your boss.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161390/discussion-between-niranjan-godbole-and-basile-starynkevitch).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing the code to make the C program a daemon I would go with an already mature tool like supervisor:

http://supervisord.org/

Answer (score 0):

I think this below will work

```
screen cmd arg1 arg2
```

You can also try

```
nohup cmd arg1
```